# How to return a value into a variable twice so that I can use them in two separate insert statements

Tags: oracle, plsql

So i am trying to store an auto-generated (from a trigger/sequence) id into a variable to use in two subsequent insert statements. However, I noticed that no data was being inserted into my second table (**temp_calc**) and I can't seem to return the same value (**calculation_id**) into two different variables. How can I use the same value returned into v_calculation_id in both insert statements? Below is my (attempted but incorrect) code:

```
insert into calculation(calculation_id, calculation_Date, calculation_name)
                VALUES(null, sysdate, 'TEST')
              returning calculation_id into v_calculation_id;
-- 
INSERT INTO calculation_trans (calculation_id, calculation_trans_type_id, create_dt)
                       values (v_calculation_id, 776, sysdate);
--
insert into temp_calc (calculation_id, flag_type_id)                            
               VALUES (v_calculation_id, 75462355);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use PL/SQL block:

```
DECLARE 
  v_calculation_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
-- removing calculation_id(it should be IDENTITY/default SEQ/trigger)
insert into calculation( calculation_Date, calculation_name)
VALUES(sysdate, 'TEST')
returning calculation_id into v_calculation_id;

INSERT INTO calculation_trans(calculation_id,calculation_trans_type_id, create_dt)
values (v_calculation_id, 776, sysdate);

insert into temp_calc (calculation_id, flag_type_id)                            
VALUES (v_calculation_id, 75462355);
COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: yes, the code above was part of my pl/sql block :) nothing is being inserted into my second insert statement though (for some odd reason)

Comment: it looks like no calculation_ids are being returned to v_calculation_id though (for some odd reason)

Comment: nevermind, i made a really silly error, i didn't even need to ask this question after all! my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

better try with a RETURNING of your primary key